# Copy individual commits between branches, preserving the SHA-1 tag

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I want to copy a commit (using its particular SHA-1 tag) from one branch to another. I want it to be an exact copy, resulting in the same SHA-1 tag.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6):

It can not be done. The SHA-1 hash of a commit is computed using the hashes of the parent commits, the commit message contents and the tree of the commit.

This means that when the parent commit changes (which it will, except if your branches point to the same commit), the SHA-1 changes too.

If your use case is to know from which commit a cherry-pick originated, use the `-x` option to `git cherry-pick`, which will add the picked commit ID to the commit message.

Comment: In short, Git uses [content-addressable storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_storage)

Answer (score 1):

`git merge` will preserve SHA1 hashes, so if you `git merge branchB` on `branchA`, the commits should have the same IDs. Of course this won't work for an individual commit, but it will work for an entire branch.